# VueJs Medium Editor installation Run through

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, medium-editor

spent hours trying to figure out how to install Medium Editor in VueJs.

I've managed to make it work on a single page vuejs. But I cannot get it to work when using the webpack file structure:

```
   ├── main.js                 # app entry file
   ├── App.vue                 # main app component
   ├── components/             # ui components
   │   │   └── ...
   │   └── assets/             # module assets
```

I've installed it via npm. Imported stylesheets and scripts. But I cannot get it to run.

I've been using https://www.npmjs.com/package/medium-editor as a guideline.

**Could you run me through where to place what?**

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is wrapper for this library written in Vue.js. 
Here is the link https://franzskuffka.github.io/vue-medium-editor/

Install using

```
npm i --save vue2-medium-editor
```

## app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import editor from 'vue2-medium-editor'

new Vue {
  components: {
    'medium-editor': editor
  }
}
```

## index.html

```
<medium-editor :text='myText' custom-tag='h2' v-on:edit='applyTextEdit'>
```

If you find any issues, open an issue in the repo.